# JS/CSS How to zoom picture by clicking with adjustable speed and execute function after this

Tags: javascript, css

I try to create an animation effect with JS/CSS, but the result is not the wished one.

The idea was to click on the image and start a function which zooms into the image until it's really huge and only one last color is seen.

If this is true, my function should open the next page.

But I don't get a smooth zoom. Do you have any idea how I could do it?

Here is my code:

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html>
         <head>

          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>TraumRaum</title>
          <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
          <style type="text/css">


              div.image {
                  width: 250px;
                  height: 250px;
                   position: fixed;
                   top: 50%;
                   left:50%;
                  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
              }
              div.image img {
                  width: 100%;
                  height: auto;
                  /* SCALE */
                  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
                  -moz-transform: scale(10);
                  -ms-transform: scale(10);
                  -o-transform: scale(10);
                  transform: scale(10);
                  /* VERZÖGERUNG */
                  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
                  -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
                  -ms-transition: all 0.1s linear;
                  -o-transition: all 0.1s linear;
                  transition: all 0.1s linear;
              }
              div.image img:hover {
                  -webkit-transform: scale(3);
                  -moz-transform: scale(3);
                  -ms-transform: scale(3);
                  -o-transform: scale(3);
                  transform: scale(3);
                  cursor: pointer;
              }
          </style>
          <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="jquery.zoomooz.min.js"></script> 
          <script type="text/javascript">
              function zoomin(){
                var yourImg = document.getElementById('yourImgId');
                 var i;
                for(i =0 ; i< 100000; i++){
                   yourImg.height = yourImg.height+1;
                   yourImg.width = yourImg.width+1;
                }
              window.open("https://www.nextwebsite.com","_self")
            }


          </script>
        </head>
      <body onmousedown="zoomin()">
        <div class = "image" >
          <class="zoomTarget" data-targetsize="1" data-duration="60000">
          <img id="logo1" src="logo.png" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        </div>

      </body>

      </html>
```

Comment: Maybe CSS animations are what you need? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: there is one hoverover action although integrated, so by overhovering the size increases, for attention on the logo. the clickevent should  zoom in then very fast, and should after getting realy huge automaticly open another page, without cklicking again

Comment: Or you use requestAnimationFrame(function) and check for the evaluation number x (in your case 100000). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 0):

If zooming in on an image is what you'd like to accomplish, perhaps just use css transitions.
Apply a starting height and width to your original, like so:

```
#logo1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and then apply either a hover or focus state which increases the height and width of the object in question. For example:

```
#logo1:hover {
  height: 500%;
  width: 500%;
```

This will give increase the image's size to 5x it's original size when hovered. If you'd like this to take place over a period of time, set a transition duration by adding "transition duration: 500ms" to #logo1. This would take 500 milliseconds to apply the change. I hope this answers your question.